# Can a rosnode have a global state of it's own?

Tags: smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I wish to create a statemachine for a rosnode. However I want the state machine to be broken into parts and execute these parts independently. E.g.
Initial State of the rosnode is A
A Service S1 is called
Then tranistion happens A->B. Now the global state of the node is B
Then when another service/action is called tranistion happens B->C , with the global state as C, and so on.

So over all my state machine is A->B->C. But the parts A->B, B->C are based on triggers for Services and Actions.
And also at a given point, the rosnode has a global state based on these transitions.
Can smach help me to get it done ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270819/can-a-rosnode-have-a-global-state-of-it%27s-own-?/) by [amarbanerjee23](https://answers.ros.org/users/30844/amarbanerjee23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-09-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amarbanerjee23](https://answers.ros.org/users/30844/amarbanerjee23/) on 2017-09-14**:
Hi @gvdhoorn @knxa !!
Sorry to pull you into this question. But as I really had some good comments from you, I thought I'll get you help over here too. What do think about this question ? A ros node can be seen as a controller node with a state. I am trying to get the node state at any moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> > Can smach help me to get it done

I guess that is exactly what SMACH is. Or what [SMACH_ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/action/show/smach/Tutorials) is, since there you get SMACH states that wraps interaction to an action server or a service, so you can create arbitrary coordination of tasks, e.g.:

'A' must happen before 'B' and if 'A' fails then 'B' is not executed, etc...

---

Originally posted by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) with karma: 811 on 2017-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0